# how to prevent model from getting filtered value in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a certain input elements which have language filters attached to them. However I need to send only the english language back to the server. I have something like this:

```
<select ng-model='dropdownModel'>
      <option>{{'some text' | translate}}</option>
</select>
```

But while submitting i need to submit only english version and not french or any other translated text. Or better, I just need the model to stick to 'some text' no matter what filter is applied. Same goes for other input elements.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the `<option value="???">` here as,

```
<select ng-model='dropdownModel'>
    <option value="{{ 'some text' }}">{{'some text' | translate}}</option>
</select>
```

if we select the first option then the `dropdownModel` is sets to `'some text'`.